# Enthought Install Canopy Windows 7 Fails Parse Error Invalid Line

Tags: python, enthought, failed-installation, canopy

I've been trying to install Canopy 64-bit on a Win 7 64bit machine. I downloaded both the quick install and the academic version. They both appear to install but fail to launch. The error message is:

Unexpected error ParseError:Invalid line line "1"

I uninstall the earlier versions of Canopy, but I'm reluctant to uninstall all my Python installations. Canopy doesn't answer bug reports and I can't afford to sacrifice my entire Python build just to get the benefits of Canopy.

During installation, I am never given the option of 'run as administrator'. I install from msi files, which don't appear to have an run-as-admin option.

Does this happen to anybody else, or do I just need to give up on Enthought?

Thanks, KC

Comment: Hi Ken, Thanks for the report and sorry for missing your reports directly to us. Looking at this issue now. Just one point of information. To install as administrator, use the procedure here: https://support.enthought.com/entries/23736288-Windows-on-some-systems-admin-users-cannot-immediately-install-for-all-users-

Answer (score 1):

(Update below)

Solution (offline communication with OP):

Log out of Windows. Log back in. Delete this directory:

```
C:\Users\<your-user-name>\Appdata\Roaming\Enthought\Canopy\
```

and restart Canopy.

This solution is a blunt axe. More precise solution to be posted when verified.

=== Updated November 2, 2013:

Log out of Windows. Log back in. Delete this file:

```
C:\Users\<your-user-name>\Appdata\Roaming\Enthought\Canopy\preferences.ini
```

and restart Canopy.